# JavaScript function to change margin of element only working on first click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a inline list of pictures that I want to be able to rotate through. I only ever display five at a time, and if you click on any besides the center one that one moves to the center and the others move on and off screen.

I wrote a function to use the `.offsetLeft` to get where one button was in relation to another and determine which way the container should move. I was hoping that I could just change the offset of the buttons and move them within the container, but sadly you can't do that with just JavaScript.

So I determined that it would be best to have a window and change the margin on the container behind by the offset difference, and this works well. The first time after that it goes each time I click a picture, and it acts like it goes through the code, but it does not change the margin of the container.

Here is the code:

```js
var cur_position;
    function set_variables() 
    {
        cur_position = document.getElementById("button3");
    }

    function carousel(Event) 
    {
        console.log(cur_position);
        var clicked_element = Event.target;
        var tray_bar = document.getElementById("button_tray");
        var num = 0;

        console.log(clicked_element.offsetLeft);
        clicked_element.offsetLeft = cur_position.offsetLeft - clicked_element.offsetLeft;
        console.log(clicked_element.offsetLeft);

        console.log(cur_position.offsetLeft);
        console.log(clicked_element.offsetLeft);

        if (clicked_element.offsetLeft < cur_position.offsetLeft) 
        {
            num = cur_position.offsetLeft - clicked_element.offsetLeft;
            console.log(cur_position.offsetLeft - num);
            document.getElementById("button_tray").style.marginLeft += num;

            cur_position = clicked_element;
            console.log(cur_position);
        }
        else
        {
            num = clicked_element.offsetLeft - cur_position.offsetLeft;
                console.log(num);
                tray_bar.style.marginLeft = tray_bar.style.marginLeft - num;

            cur_position = clicked_element;
            console.log(cur_position);
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">
            <ul id="button_tray" class="buttons">
              <li id="button1" class="message-button" onclick="carousel(event)"><div></div></li>
              <li id="button2" class="link-button" onclick="carousel(event)"><div></div> </li>
              <li id="button3" class="live-button" onclick="carousel(event)"><div></div> </li>
              <li id="button4" class="social-button" onclick="carousel(event)"><div></div></li>
              <li id="button5" class="ppt-button" onclick="carousel(event)"><div></div> </li>
              <li id="button6" class="test-1" onclick="carousel(event)"><div></div></li>
              <li id="button7" class="test-2" onclick="carousel(event)"><div></div></li>
              <li id="button8" class="test-3" onclick="carousel(event)"><div></div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would really like to figure out why it's only working the first time or even better be able to move the pictures inside in relation to one another. Please keep answers in JavaScript instead of jQuery.

Comment: create a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net) it will be easier to help

Comment: There are many problems with this code. Jacob outlined one. Also: using IE-only properties, not calling `set_variables`, inline JS, etc., etc.  This is a perfect opportunity (and another example) to step-up to jQuery.

Comment: set_variables is a onload function in the body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the only issue, but when you're setting your margins, you're not taking units or the data type of styles into account.  With this line:

```
document.getElementById("button_tray").style.marginLeft += num;
```

Your first access of `marginLeft` may be a blank string, so `+= num` would work properly.  If `num` was set to 20, browser may convert the style property to `20px`.  The next time around, when you accessed `marginLeft`, you'd get back `"20px"`; adding 20 to that would result in `"20px20"`, which is obviously not a good value.

I'd suggest that when you want to add to or remove from the margin property, you should do it like this instead:

```
var tray_bar = document.getElementById("button_tray");
var pixelMargin = parseInt(tray_bar.style.marginLeft, 10);
pixelMargin += num;
tray_bar.style.marginLeft = pixelMargin.toString() + 'px';
```

Comment: I ended up changing it a little the way this is set up right now if you log pixelMargin.toString() + 'px' it returns NaNpx but I got past that and it works now thanks for the help.